# Dynamically change actionbar.tab text (title) color

Tags: android, colors, tabs, android-actionbar, title

I need to change the color and/or the shadow of my tab title.
I've tried it but doesnt work:

```
public void iluminarTab(String target) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.getTabAt(getTabPositionByTitle(target));
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(tab.getText().toString());
    ss.setSpan(
            new ShadowSpan(4, 0, 0, getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.irc_color_13_pink)), 0, ss.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tab.setText(ss);
}

private Integer getTabPositionByTitle(String title) {
    for (int i = 0; i < actionBar.getTabCount(); i++) {
        if (actionBar.getTabAt(i).getText().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// NOTE: a separated class, posting here just to explain.
// this works on other spannables
public class ShadowSpan extends CharacterStyle {
    public float Dx;
    public float Dy;
    public float Radius;
    public int Color;

    public ShadowSpan(int radius, int dx, int dy, int color) {
        Radius = radius;
        Dx = dx;
        Dy = dy;
        Color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setShadowLayer(Radius, Dx, Dy, Color);
    }
}
```

If i could just set the textview atributes it would help me too.
Any Idea to help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the view for your tab with `getCustomView()`, then call `setBackgroundResource()` on it.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tab.getCustomView(); //get the view for the tab
    tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.id.desired_background_with_indicator); // change the background
    tab.setCustomView(tabLayout); // assign back to the tab
}
```

Although I used `onTabSelected`, in your case you already have a reference for `ActionBar.Tab` in your methods, use the `tab` object in same way.

You can use a `ColorDrawable` for background or whatever suits you best.

Comment: getCustomView returned null;